# Correct Translation for artificial horizon

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

I would like to draw an artificial horizon. The center of the view would represent perfectly horizontal view with roll rotating the horizontal line and pitch moving it up or down.

The question is: what is the correct calculation to translate the horizon line up or down (pitch) given the pitch angle.

My guess is that this would probably depend on the FOV angle that one would assume for an assumed camera, so this angle would need to be a factor in the algorithm sought. Ideally I would figure out this angle for the iPhone/iPad camera so that the artificial horizon would line up with the actual horizon if you hold the device in front of you and look towards the horizon.

Until now I've been guesstimating the offset, but I would like to have the exact formula.

Comment: Try `horizon_offset/(screen_height/2)=tan(pitch)/tan(vertical_FOV/2)`. [See](http://zwibbler.com/shared/3120.png).

Comment: Could you write that as a separate answer so that I can accept it if it turns out to be the correct one? Possibly also elaborating as to how you derived the formula?

Comment: An exact answer depends on knowing how far the user is from the screen, and the angle at which it is being held - if the screen is not viewed exactly at 90 degrees, then the angle of the device won't translate to the angle of the horizon. Hence sextants and quadrants have more than one sight to line up. Artificial horizons in aircraft instead show a calibrated scale for pitch so they don't require such information.

Comment: http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/971159 has focal length for iphone cameras.

Comment: @PeteKirkham how would I calculate the angle from the focal length in mm? So what is the formula you would suggest for my question?

Comment: @PeteKirkham: A mobile phone doesn't have any implements to align the user's aim. The software just has to assume he's looking straight to the center of the screen, holding the device perpendicularly to his line of sight. Which is of course not true in general, but should not bee very far from the truth in most cases, because this is the position that gives the user most picture quality. There's no dependence on the viewing distance, because the horizon is infinitely far.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I'm sorry you are right, it does depend on the viewing distance. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Cocoanetics: Yes much better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try horizon_offset/(screen_height/2)=tan(pitch)/tan(vertical_FOV/2).

Look at the picture, and the formula derives itself.

[image: the picture]
<sub>(source: [zwibbler.com](http://zwibbler.com/shared/3120.png))</sub>
.

**Update** I have two angles mixed up. One is the FOV angle of the *camera*, the other is the viewing angle of the *screen*. These are two different things. The latter depends on the viewing distance. You probably have to estimate this distance, and adjust magnification and/or focal distance such that objects visible on the screen are the same angular size as the same objects visible with the naked eye. (With my particular phone, you would need to magnify the image by an additional factor of about 3 after the 5x zoom, if the user stretches his hand with the phone all the way forward). Then the two angles are the same, and the formula works.

If you want to introduce magnification (i.e. objects on the screen have different sizes from their real-life counterparts), multiply the horizon offset by the magnification factor.

**Update 2** When taking the viewing distance into account, the screen size cancels out, and the offset simply becomes `viewing_distance*tan(pitch_angle)` (with unit magnification).

Comment: If I changed the pitch would the horizon move linear or faster the further I am away from horizonal? What if I roll the device 90 degrees and thus the screen hight becomes wider? Assume the same factor? Do I solve the formula for horizon_offset by multiplying with (screen_height/2)

Comment: Also, wouldn't the vertical FOV be the same as the horizonal one?

Comment: Now when I look at it again, screen size cancels out, and the offset simply becomes viewing_distance*tan(pitch_angle) (with unit magnification).

Comment: How would I arrive at an amount of pixels then? Because viewing distance would be measured in cm, right? And what is "unit magnification?

Comment: You need to know the physical pixel density of the screen. For Android devices it is in the DisplayMetrics struct. Unit magnification is magnification factor of 1. That is, real objects and their images on the screen (viewed at a given distance) are of the same angular size.